# How to purge a folder under windows?

Tags: delete-file, data-recovery, purge

I would like to create a utility which delete the folder from windows machine permanently. This we can do it easily from any programming language.

But my challenge is that, the deleted folder can't be recoverable from any Tool in market.

So please suggest me how it can be possible? i.e. using c, c++, C# or java.

Thanks,
Laxmilal Menaria

Comment: There are tons of tools for that http://www.howtogeek.com/72130/learn-how-to-securely-delete-files-in-windows/

Comment: I don't need any tools, I would like to create a program myself. Which I can integrate it our app.

Comment: There are command line tools that you can integrate into your app